# How can I force quit inside "openssl s_client -connect"?

Tags: scripting, openssl

I am writing a script that calls the command.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server:9999 > out.pem -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -pass pass:password
```

But it displays an output, I tried adding -quiet but with no luck.  Is there a way I can get it so that it won't report to the console.  If I run the command in terminal I have to type exit to get out of the connection.

I want this to exit automatically within my script.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is the problem that there is output to the console, or that the call doesn't exit automatically?

Comment: It doesn't call exit automatically, is there a way to make it too that?

Comment: I am guessing that `openssl s_client` is executing its dashed commands in order (in this case `-showcerts` first, then `-connect X`). I looked for a `-quit` to add to the end, but cannot find one in the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is possibly being sent to stderr (rather than stdout).  It should work if you use `>&` for the redirection.

Comment: OK that stopped the output, but is there a way to make it automatically exit as well?

Comment: @Matt: I am not sure about that and currently don't have the necessary certificates in place to test it.  But maybe you can change the command to redirect input from a file with the appropriate command:  `< inputresponse.txt`

Comment: This could work what is that command called? Could i use a sting instead of a file?

Comment: @Matt:  It may may simply work if the input file is empty.  Or if [a line begins with a Q apparently](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).

Answer (score 8):

For the automatically exit part, you could do this:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443
```

Comment: This seems to work very well. Anyone know why it works? What shell trick does it employ?

Comment: It's not a shell trick. `openssl s_client` is waiting for user input.  It waits for a CR/LF (Enter key).  The "echo" piped into `openssl` simulates that.  After receiving that, `openssl` exits.

Comment: You can also `openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 </dev/null` it has the same result